# Unable to locate the server named argocd-repo-server

Tags: argocd

We trying to create a new repository connection and getting this error

```
*rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.1 504 Unknown Host\\r\\nContent-Length: 666\\r\\nCache-Control: no-store\\r\\nContent-Language: en\\r\\nContent-Type: text/html\\r\\nDate: Tue, 07 Feb 2023 15:49:56 GMT\\r\\n\\r\\n<HEAD><TITLE>Unknown Host</TITLE></HEAD>\\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\\\"white\\\" FGCOLOR=\\\"black\\\"><H1>Unknown Host</H1><HR>\\n<FONT FACE=\\\"Helvetica,Arial\\\"><B>\\nDescription: Unable to locate the server named \\\"<em>argocd-repo-server</em>\\\" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.</B></FONT>\\n<HR>\\n<!-- default \\\"Unknown Host\\\" response (504) -->\\n</BODY>\\n \\x00\""*
```

The repo server is up and running and we mange to access to it in cluster
To Reproduce
argocd repo add http://git.example.com/repos/repo --username git --password --insecure-skip-server-verification

Version

```
argocd: v2.5.6+9db2c94
  BuildDate: 2023-01-10T19:30:17Z
  GitCommit: 9db2c9471f6ff599c3f630b446e940d3a065620b
  GitTreeState: clean
  GoVersion: go1.18.9
  Compiler: gc
  Platform: linux/amd64
FATA[0000] Argo CD server address unspecified
```

We trying to create a new repository connection and getting this error

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing failed to do connect handshake, response: \"HTTP/1.1 504 Unknown Host\\r\\nContent-Length: 666\\r\\nCache-Control: no-store\\r\\nContent-Language: en\\r\\nContent-Type: text/html\\r\\nDate: Tue, 07 Feb 2023 15:49:56 GMT\\r\\n\\r\\n<HEAD><TITLE>Unknown Host</TITLE></HEAD>\\n<BODY BGCOLOR=\\\"white\\\" FGCOLOR=\\\"black\\\"><H1>Unknown Host</H1><HR>\\n<FONT FACE=\\\"Helvetica,Arial\\\"><B>\\nDescription: Unable to locate the server named \\\"<em>argocd-repo-server</em>\\\" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again.</B></FONT>\\n<HR>\\n<!-- default \\\"Unknown Host\\\" response (504) -->\\n</BODY>\\n \\x00\""
```

Answer (score 0):

if whatever this repo is http://git.example.com/repos/repo , try to change to https instead of http